# How to make flex container fill browser window height (with scrolling complications)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container `<main>` between a `<header>` and a `<footer>`, and in that container I have a number of columns. I have set up horizontal scrolling of `<main>` to hanle the case of too many columns to display at once, and I've also enabled vertical scrolling on a sub-division of the columns. The intent is that the header is anchored at the top of the window, the footer at the bottom of the window, and the space between is used to display the columns, with scrolling as needed.

```
<header>HEADER</header>
<main class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <h3>column 1</h3>
    <div class="content">
      long content that would scroll
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column"><h3>col2</h3><div class="content">...</div></div>
  <div class="column"><h3>col3</h3><div class="content">...</div></div>
  <div class="column"><h3>col4</h3><div class="content">...</div></div>
  <div class="column"><h3>col5</h3><div class="content">...</div></div>
</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

```
/* trimmed css */
header,
footer { }

main {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.column {
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.column .content {
  height: 570px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image: columns, between header & footer]

I've got most of all that working here https://codepen.io/ericscheid/pen/mdMwyEE

The demo currently hard-codes a `height: 600px;` for the columns. (Also the `div.column div.content` is set to `height: 570px;`, which is an unsatisfactory magic number hack to get scrolling working right, and which breaks if any of the `div.column h3` elements spills onto two lines.)

*However, I can't figure out how to get the columns container element to fill the available height of the browser window.* I've tried setting various heights to 100%, setting using `display:inline-block` ... but at this point I'm only poking guesses into a black box.

**How can I get the columns to fill the available height?** And have the scolling work correctly (e.g. if any have an extra large `<h3>`). (I'd rather not involve javascript to dynamically calculate heights, etc, if at all reasonably possible).

Comment: You can wrap your content around a wrapper with a max-height: 100vh https://jsfiddle.net/93mkL0s8/

Comment: Like @mulsun said, wrap all elements in a container with `flex-direction: column`. If your header and footer are fixed heights you could also change the `height` of your `main` to `height: calc(100vh - 120px);`

Comment: @mulsun I was unsure if the wrapper was around the columns, the main, .. or the entire content. Thank you for the fiddle.

Comment: @mulsen oh .. tweaking the solution reveals other tricks, like it's not the content that is scrolling in its own space, but is instead sliding up under and behind the h3. All good.